# Spin-statistics theorem on spaces with non-integer dimensions

Tags: spin-statistics, fractals

What would be the spin-statistics relation for particles in a space with non-integer dimension, $ 2 \lt D \lt 3 $? In other words (cf. stackexchange questions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65767/what-is-the-reason-why-anyons-escape-spin-statistic-theorem) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41868/can-closed-loops-evade-the-spin-statistic-theorem-in-3-dimensions)), what is the first homotopy group for a space with non-integer dimension, $ 2 \lt D \lt 3 $?

Although it is not useful for my immediate work, I would also like to know for fractional dimensions $ 0 \lt D \lt 2 $ and $ 3 \lt D \lt \infty $

References/reviews, written for physicists, will also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is an answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/21964/